# Calculating for acceleration in Python

Tags: python

I want to calculate a car's acceleration in mph. The initial velocity is 0, the final velocity is 60 and the time is meant to be inputted by the user in seconds. I know the equation for acceleration is (final velocity - initial velocity)/time.

However, I'm not sure how to get it into mph and how my equation needs to be modified. Here's my code so far:

```
time = 0
acceleration = 0
initial_velocity = 0
final_velocity = 60
print('Inputt the time required for the care to reach 60 mph in seconds.')
time = float(input())
acceleration = (final_velocity - initial_velocity)/time
print('The acceleration of the car is:' acceleration')
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3, the [`input()` function always returns a string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input).

You will need to parse it to a number - in your case, a floating point number, parsed with [`float()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#float) is what you need:

```
time = float(input())
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [python doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input), `inputs` converts user input to a string, so you need to convert it to a numeric type first.

Also, to obtain a real result you must first convert `time` to hours or `final_velocity` to mps.

To implement the first option, you could add:

```
timeInHours = time/3600.0
acceleration = (final_velocity - initial_velocity)/timeInHours
```

Answer (score 0):

python input take input in string form, so you have to convert it into a float or at least

```
time = float(input())
time = int(input())
```

and also there two error in your last line

1. Misplaced backquote (`) after acceleration
2. In print string and variable should be separated with comma (,).

```
print('The acceleration of the car is:', acceleration)
```